# Converting a large MP3 to video

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, video-encoding

I have 6 MP3 files that are between 1.2GB and 2.8GB in length.  I also have 6 image files.  I want to make 6 videos using those 6 MP3s and images.

- I have tried using uMusic to merge these and while it did work the quality was awful and it was very slow.
- Alternatively I did also try mp3toolbox.net but while it was fast it does not support the large files I am using.
- I see I can use ffmpeg but I don't know which command-line arguments to use.

Is there any way I can get better quality out of uMusic or is there a better way to achieve what I am after?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the example from the [FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images#Addingaudio), but use Matroska as an output container, since it supports H.264 video and MP3 audio:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -i audio.mp3 \
  -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p \
  -c:a copy -shortest out.mkv
```

Make sure to [use the `-pix_fmt` option](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20video%20slideshow%20from%20images#Colorspaceconversionandchromasub-sampling) to select the right colorpace. Otherwise, some players might not show the video.

Since you're copying the audio stream, no quality is lost in the process. You can improve the video quality by adding the `-crf 18` option, where [CRF sets the quality](http://slhck.info/articles/crf).

ffmpeg should not have any problem with large MP3 files, although I wonder why they have to be that large. Unless it's 24 hours worth of material.

Comment: It's 70 to 80 hours worth of material per file :)

Comment: How do I use Matroska as the output container?

Comment: … you do it by using `out.mkv` as an output file (or anything that ends with `.mkv`). I just hightlighted the main difference between the command I gave you and the one on the FFmpeg wiki.

Comment: This command works great! Finally managed to render my music with a picture! :)